# md5 checksum getting changed in subsequent run with same output

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to save the list of users in a log file with checksum and match the output for next occurrence when the user list changed and execute a statement based on that. I came up with below script but the "newhash" variable is generating a new hash value even when the user list hasn't changed. Any help with what i'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
listuser=$(awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} $3 >= 1000 && $3<=65534 {print $1,$6}' /etc/passwd)
echo -e "$listuser" | md5sum > /var/log/current_users.log
hashfile=/var/log/current_users.log
newhash=$("$listuser" | md5sum)
oldhash=$(cat $hashfile)
if [[ "newhash" != "oldhash" ]]; then
        echo "test"
fi
echo "$newhash" > /
var/log/current_users.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic line is

```
newhash=$("$listuser" | md5sum)
```

it should be

```
newhash=$(echo "$listuser" | md5sum)
```

The former executes the content of listuser as it it was a command.

EDIT: as noted by user1934428, another problem is that "$" before identifiers is missing in "newhash" != "oldhash"

Comment: It's not the only problematic line. The OP actually never compares the hashes, but he compares the string _newhash_ to the string _oldhash_, and they will always be different, because they are different strings. Then, he does not have two different "occurances" of a user list: The actual user list is stored in hashfile, and that very same information goes into `md5sum` twice, once called "oldhash" and once called "newhash".  IMO, the whole script doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Correct! I stopped reading at the very first problem... Added a note; and +1 for you